# In C++20, is the sentinel type of a forward range guaranteed to be the same type as its iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20

A forward range `r` requires that its iterator is in turn a forward iterator, which in turns requires that the iterator works as its own sentinel. But, does it imply that the actual sentinel type (e.g., the type returned by `r.end()`) is of the same type as the iterator itself or doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not, but it has to be
`__WeaklyEqualityComparableWith` (an exposition-only `concept`) the iterator type returned by `begin()` as can be seen in the [`std::sentinel_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sentinel_for) `concept` which is a concept that ...

> specifies the relationship between an [`input_or_output_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_or_output_iterator) type and a [`semiregular`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/semiregular) type whose values denote a range. The exposition-only concept `__WeaklyEqualityComparableWith` is described in [`equality_comparable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable).

The `sentinel_for` concept is used by [`std::ranges:end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/end) which can be seen in its call signature:

```cpp
template< class T >
    requires /* see link */
constexpr std::sentinel_for<ranges::iterator_t<T>> auto end( T&& t );
```

This note in `sentinel_for` is also of interest:

> A sentinel type and its corresponding iterator type are not required to model [`equality_comparable_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable), because the sentinel type may not be comparable with itself, and they are not required to have a common reference type.

Comment: But which other "concept" do require that `decltype(r.end())` is `sentinel_for decltype(r.begin())`? I have only seen that the iterator type must work as sentinel, but I haven't seen (in cppreference) any `concept` or requirement that says `sentinel_for<decltype(r.end()), decltype(r.begin())>` or similar. If I woudn't have seen that, I would have known that it's indeed not enforced to be of the same type, but its absence made my unsure about that.

Comment: @ABu  The absense of the requirement in the `input_iterator` concept may provide more info: _"Unlike the LegacyInputIterator requirements, the `input_iterator` concept does not require equality_comparable, since input iterators are typically compared with sentinels."_

Comment: @ABu: What you're looking for is [called `common_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_range). However, you should *only* employ it when you absolutely *must*. And really, this would only be needed if you're going to manipulate the end iterator as an iterator. Which for a forward range... is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

None of the basic range type concepts (input, forward, bidirectional, etc) require the sentinel to be an iterator. Even a `contiguous_range` can work with a sentinel rather than an iterator. However, the [concept `common_range` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_range). So you can combine that concept with one of the basic range concepts.

But you should only ever employ this when you actually need to manipulate the end sentinel as an iterator. Which for a strictly forward range... is not actually possible. You can't dereference it, since dereferencing the end iterator is bad. You can't decrement it, since it's a forward range; it's iterators can't go backwards.

Basically, there's never a reason for a template that takes a `forward_range` to also require that it is a `common_range`.